# Переменная которая бы содержала исключительно домен первого уровня в nginx

Tags: nginx

```
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)$) {
    return 301 https://site.ru$request_uri;
}
```

Есть ли в конфигурации переменная которая содержала бы исключительно домен первого уровня. В данном примере выполняю переадресацию c www на без www. Вынужден данное условие прописывать для каждого сайта.

Рассчитываю найти решение, при котором возможно данное правило вынести выше и сделать его для всех сайтов. Чтобы не прописывать для каждого сайта отдельно.

Второй вопрос, каким образом возможно добавить в условие и тоже выполнить перенаправление в том случаи если сайт открыт не по протоколу https

Comment: `if ($host ~ ^www\.(?<domain>.+)$) { return 301 $scheme://$domain$request_uri; }`

Comment: А для показанного вами конфига наверно просто достаточно заменить `site.ru` на `$1` и всё заработает, потому что вы уже завернули кусок домена без www в скобки `(.*)` и таким образом создали переменную